# How to apply multiprocessing in python3.x for the following nested loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
for i in range(1,row):
    for j in range(1,col):
        if i > j and i != j:
            x = Aglo[0][i][0]
            y = Aglo[j][0][0]
            Aglo[j][i] = offset.myfun(x,y)
            Aglo[i][j] = Aglo[j][i]
```

Aglo[][] is a 2D array, which consists of lists in the first row
offset.myfun() is a function defined elsewhere

This might be a trivial question but i couldn't understand how to use multiprocessing for these nested loops as x,y (used in myfun()) is different for each process(if multiprocessing is used)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your code right, you are not overwriting any previously calculated values. If that's true, then you can use multiprocessing. If not, then you can't guarantee that the results from multiprocessing will be in the correct order.

To use something like `multiprocessing.Pool`, you would need to gather all valid (x, y) pairs to pass to `offset.myfun()`. Something like this might work (untested):

```
pairs = [(i, j, Aglo[0][i][0], Aglo[j][0][0]) for i in range(1, row) for j in range(1, col) if i > j and i != j]
# offset.myfun now needs to take a tuple instead of x, y
# it additionally needs to emit i and j in addition to the return value
# e.g. (i, j, result)
p = Pool(4)
results = p.map(offset.myfun, pairs)
# fill in Aglo with the results
for pair in pairs:
    i, j, value = pair
    Aglo[i][j] = value
    Aglo[j][i] = value
```

You will need to pass in i and j to `offset.myfun` because otherwise there is no way to know which result goes where. `offset.myfun` should then return i and j along with the result so you can fill in Aglo appropriately. Hope this helps.